# DISOBEYING FATHER FOR NOT DOING HARAM JOB

Tags: halal-haram, allah, riba, family, banking

Asslamualikum!

I was a finance student back 2 years ago. You know that doing job in a bank is haram as it involves Interest so due to this reason my aim was to do a job in a company as they aren't indulge in interest. But my father wanted me to do a job in a bank as there was a reference. But I refused from day one due to above mentioned reasons. And got a job in a Cargo company as Data entry specialist. My father become unhappy as so my whole family.

Things become more worse when I discover my colleagues having poor and absurd mentality in the company. But still I was happy that I was doing a Halal job.

But after 3 months a rider and then my director sales harassed me. Due to which I got Bipolar mental disorder. And I have to be admitted in hospital for 10 days and left job eventually.

Now I want to ask you is that was a punishment from Allah not obeying my father as I haven't recovered yet. Whenever I find a new job (after that incident) I got fired after some months.

I used to listen that when you avoid haram things and do halal things Allah become happy but I am puzzled on the things happening around me. Please guide me for the sake of Allah I am completely hopeless.

Please reply me it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

*is that was a punishment from Allah not obeying my father*

God does not usually intervene immediately on our deeds, neither the good deeds nor the bad deeds. He admonishes us to be good and patient.

Yunus 10:108

> Say, “O people, the truth has come to you from your Lord. Whoever
> accepts guidance is guided for his own soul; and whoever strays only
> strays to its detriment. I am not a guardian over you.” And follow
> what is revealed to you, and be patient until God issues His judgment,
> for He is the Best of judges.

*I used to listen that when you avoid haram things and do halal things Allah become happy*

You did right not to enter in the business of taking interest, knowing it is haram. One is our Guardian, Allah. He commanded us to respect our parents. But he did not tell us to follow their commandment if it is against His commandment.

As you said, *after 3 months a rider and then my director sales harassed* you. That is not *your* fault, it is *their* fault. You are the victim, not the guilty.

Let professional (psychiatrist) and good friends help you to come over it. And trust in Allah our God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

Al-Bayyina 98:7-8

> As for those who believe and lead a righteous life—these are the best
> of creatures. Their reward is with their Lord: Gardens of Eternity
> beneath which rivers flow, where they will abide forever. God is
> pleased with them, and they are pleased with Him. That is for whoever
> fears His Lord.